# mysql group by after removing some columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with 3 relevant columns.

```
column1    column2   column3    
  12          NULL      13      
  12          stuff     14      
  13          stuff2    15      
  13          NULL      14      
  14          stuff2    15      
  14          NULL      16
```

I want to run an sql query which gives my the count of rows grouped by column1 where column2 is null and column3 is not 14. So the query should return something like this -

```
14 1
12 1
```

It will not return any row whose column1 is 13 because for rows where column1 is 13 column3 is 14.

NOTE : I don't want to use views for this.

Comment: `where column2 is not null and column3 is not 14`, yet you rule 12 out, but there is no single record where column1 is 12 and column2 is null and column3 is 14. Do you want to filter those column1 values out, where any of the records contain column2 with null and column3 with 14? Also, pls share what you have done to achieve the desired output!

Comment: @Shadow `where column2 is null and column3 is not 14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT column1, SUM(column2 IS NULL AND column3 <> 14) AS total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column1
HAVING total > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo*`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424812)**</kbd>

<sup>*SQLFiddle is no responding so SQL Server equivalent</sup>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ column1 ║ total ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║      14 ║     1 ║
║      12 ║     1 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

How it works:

1. Condition `true` as 1, `false` as 0
2. `SUM` per group (column1)
3. `HAVING total > 0` filter out `13`

   ```
   ╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
   ║ column1 ║ column2 ║ column3 ║  condition  ║
   ╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
   ║      12 ║ NULL    ║      13 ║ true        ║
   ║      12 ║ stuff   ║      14 ║ false       ║
   ║      13 ║ stuff2  ║      15 ║ false       ║
   ║      13 ║ NULL    ║      14 ║ false       ║
   ║      14 ║ stuff2  ║      15 ║ true        ║
   ║      14 ║ NULL    ║      16 ║ false       ║
   ╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
   ```

---

It can be even simpler (if you want to eliminate groups with 0 of course), just:

```
SELECT column1, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table_name
WHERE column2 IS NULL 
  AND column3 <> 14
GROUP BY column1
```

One more thing:

> column3 is not 14

If column3 is nullable you may need to use:

```
 WHERE column2 IS NULL 
   AND (column3 <> 14 OR column3 IS NULL)
```